# AJAX no encuentra el metodo en el controlador ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un controlador que tiene el siguiente metodo:

```
[HttpGet]
 public string ListaMaster()
 {
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(servicio.ListarData());
 }
```

y en mi archivo de JS tengo un boton que llama el metodo usando AJAX:

```
$('.showMaster').click(function () {


        //TRAE LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA
        $.ajax({
            url: "ListaMaster",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta) {
                console.log(respuesta);
            }
        });

    });
```

Resulta que cuando lo pruebo no me muestra nada en consola y en el Network me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es que lo que esta mal que ni siquiera entra al metodo? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en tu Javascript, tienes que entender que las URLs generadas por el framework de ASP.net MVC tienen una forma de trabajar diferente a poner la url "directa" en Javascript, dicho en código:

Reemplaza:

```
url: "ListaMaster",
```

Por:

```
url: "@Url.Action("ListaMaster","NombreDelControlador")",
```